# How to change activity in android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am making simple game. I have 3 activities. First activity is main menu (FirstActivity class).
First activity has following code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);  
startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
```

It calls second activity where, second activity has following code:

```
setContentView(new MovementView(this));
```

MovementView class extends SurfaceView. MovementView class is where I write all game code.

So I want to make when lives == 0, it changes to ThirdActivity. How do I do that?
I have tried putting code similar to FirstActivity's class but it doesn't seems to work.
If I put
 `((Activity)getContext()).finish();`
it just jumps back to FirstActivity, but that's not what I need, I need it to go to ThirdActivity class.

Comment: "I have tried putting code similar to FirstActivity's class but it doesn't seems to work." -- It should work if you put in ThirdActivity.class. What code did you write, and what "didn't work" about it? What happened instead?

Comment: @Yoni Samlan, well if I put `Intent i = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class); startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);` it shows _The constructor Intent(MovementView, Class<ThirdActivity>) is undefined_ for first line one and _The method startActivityForResult(Intent, int) is undefined for the type MovementView_ for the second line.

Comment: You appear to be calling new Intent(this, GameOver.class) from within MovementView, so 'this' is a View not a Context. You need use the Activity passed to MovementView in the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I can answer, had to wait 24h.
So in the end the only variant which I managed to make work was like this:
FirstActivity class:
on click

```
private void startGame() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

SecondActivity class:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
setContentView(new MovementView(this));
}        
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, GameOver/*GameOver=ThirdActivity*/.class);
        startActivity(i);
        super.onDestroy(); 
    }
```

MovementView class:

```
if (lives == 0){            
updateThread.setRunning(false);
((Activity)getContext()).finish();
}
```

I don't know is that the difference between onDestroy and onStop but both work. 
The only unpleasant thing is that when lives == 0 it goes back to FirstActivity (for like half second) and only then to GameOver class.

Answer (score 2):

It didn't work when you tried it because you're trying to create an intent from a View, not an Activity. You'll need to use the view's context (`getContext()`) instead of `this`. You'll also need to use `startActivity` rather than `startActivityForResult`, unless you're actually planning to use the result (although casting the context to an Activity should be fairly safe if you're only using it from your own code).

Answer (score 1):

Since you start **Activity2** with `..ForResult()`, you could also set the 2nd Activity's result (with `setResult(GAME_OVER)` before you finish it) so that **Activity1** starts **Activity3** in `onActivityResult()` if it makes sense that **Activity2** is not there anymore when **Activity3** was shown...

**RE:** @Yoni Samlan, well if I put

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
```

It shows *The constructor Intent(MovementView, Class) is undefined* for first line, and *The method startActivityForResult(Intent, int) is undefined for the type MovementView* for the second line.

You should pass your `Activity` as first argument and not the view, and call `Activity.startActivityForResult()`...
So pass your `Activity` to your view and use it there as described.

Answer (score 0):

with the MovementView constructor you have to remember the activity, tu use it to launch the third activity.

```
private Activity a;

public MovementView(Acitivity a) {
  this.a = a;
  // your code
}
```

somewhere in MovementView, replace

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
```

by

```
Intent i = new Intent(a, ThirdActivity.class);
```